# Cannot connect to server at work, see Google error page instead

Tags: networking, redirection

I use a server at work that I use to host a blog, wiki, and a few other applications that I often use from home. Today I tried to access the server from my laptop (Macbook, OS 10.5.8, Firefox 12.0) and I started seeing some strange behavior. When I requested the page **myserver.edu/mywiki**, I got a Google 404 error page. I tried a few other pages on the server (that I could remember off the top of my head), but I got the same result. When I tried the server root index page (**myserver.edu**) I got completely redirected to the Google home page.

In the last few days, we've set up new internet service at our house, so I thought something might be wrong there. But I was able to see the page correctly from our desktop (on the same network). So then I thought there might be some strange browser caching issue, and I cleared the entire cache history, but *that* didn't work either. I tried different browsers and even a different account on my laptop, but all have the same problem.

There is some system-wide issue that is causing my laptop to think that **myserver.edu** is **google.com**. I checked the `/private/etc/hosts` file--I didn't see anything out of the ordinary, although I am not sure what to expect either. Any thoughts as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the dns server configured in your laptop? try switching to Google's dns servers: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`; or openDNS: `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`.

Comment: Well, I didn't even have to change DNS servers--I just flushed my DNS cache (`dscacheutile -flushcache` for OS 10.5) and the problem went away. Thanks!